# SASS variable with media query leads to "Invalid CSS after '@'"

Tags: sass

Basic idea would be to define my media query in one place. My current attempt looks like so:

```
$mobile: "@media (max-width: 600px):not(#app.force-desktop)";


#{$mobile} {
  ...
}
```

However this results in the error: `SassError: Invalid CSS after "@": expected selector, was "@media (max-width: "` Setting $mobile to (for example) only `:not(#app.force-desktop)` seems to compile properly.

Maybe there is a different way how to solve this issue, which would be totally fine by me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just remove the `@media`:

```css
$mobile: '(max-width: 600px):not(#app.force-desktop)';

@media #{$mobile} {
    body {
        color: blue;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks that works ... though it seems the :not part is not valid CSS anyhow ... guess I'll have to go for a mixin approach instead. Oh well.

Comment: Oh, I didn't even notice that. Yeah the `:not` would have to go inside the media query